# How to send JSON payload to RabbitMQ using the web plugin?

Tags: python, json, queue, rabbitmq

I have a [RabbitMQ 3.4.2 instance](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) with a web management plugin installed.

When I push to the message `{'operationId': 194}` to the queue using Python's [kombu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kombu) queue package, the message is read on the other end as a dictionary.

However, when I send the message using the web console:

[image]

I get the following error on the receiving end:

```
operation_id = payload['operationId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have tried adding a `content-type` header and property, with no success.

Since the reader code is the same, it means that the web sender does not mark the sent message as a JSON / dictionary payload, and therefore it is read as a string on the other end.

**Any idea how to mark a message as a JSON message using the RabbitMQ web console?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had to use `content_type` instead of `content-type` (an underscore instead of a hyphen).

This is a pretty questionable design decision, because the standard everybody knows is [**`content-type`**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html).

[image]

Comment: It's not a HTTP Header... It's to distinguish that from said key as well as adhere to the RabbitMQ convention of using underscores for its properties.

Answer (score 3):

You need to de-serialize the output.

```
import json
payload = json.loads(payload)
operation_id = payload['operationId']
```

In addition `{'operationId': 194}` is not valid JSON. Although it looks like you use double quotes in the screenshot, but make sure you replace the single quotes with double quotes.

**Edit:**
So you are correct, kombu should handle this. Looking at the code it's likely that the header is case-sensitive. Change the properties header from `Content-Type` to `content-type`.

Comment: The funny thing is that messages sent from Python code requires no deserialization on the receiving end; therefore, I guess there is some metadata that does the job for me. When I send `{'operationId': 194}` it is received as a dictionary on the other end. I want to have this behaviour when sending from the web console, too.

Comment: @AdamMatan You are right. I think this might be as silly as the Header name being case-sensitive.

Comment: I should have picked up on that. I have the same implementation using a ```_``` in my own amqp library. https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/blob/master/amqpstorm/message.py#L208

Comment: Nice one! Why did you build your own instead of using Kombu or alike?

Comment: I wanted something much simpler, with a background thread to keep track of heartbeats etc.